# How to add space character after hyperlink in DraftJS?

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, draftjs

I am having trouble implementing following scenario using DraftJS API.

Here is the scenario:
Following the Link example provided on [this](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/master/examples/link/link.html)

I am using the following code to convert a selected text into Hyperlink after when user confirms the hyperlink URL:

```
_confirmLink(urlValue) {
    const {editorState} = this.state;
    const entityKey = Entity.create('LINK', 'MUTABLE', {url: urlValue});

    this.setState({
      showURLInput: false,
      editorState: RichUtils.toggleLink(
        editorState,
        editorState.getSelection(),
        entityKey
      )
    }, () => 
      setTimeout(() => this.refs.editor.focus(), 100);
    });
}
```

Now suppose user has typed text `abc` and then he supplies url for it in the prompt e.g `http://yahoo.com`
Text `abc` is converted to hyperlink, fine cool.

But after that cursor in text editor slips immediately to the start of line. When user manually tries to move that cursor to the end of line and types again something, text editor shows that typed text at start of line which is quite weird.

In my opinion a space character should be inserted after the generated hyperlink, so that user is able to type something after that. Also cursor must stay at end of hyperlink rather than at start of line.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the answer after playing for long.

Basically first, I have to collapse my selection to the end of my converted link, then using Modifier I inserted a space character after that.

Here's the code:

```
_confirmLink(urlValue) {

    const {editorState} = this.state;

    const entityKey = Entity.create(
      'LINK',
      'MUTABLE',
      {url: urlValue}
    );

    let selection = editorState.getSelection();

    const contentState = Modifier.applyEntity(
      editorState.getCurrentContent(),
      selection,
      entityKey
    );

    let linked = EditorState.push(
      editorState,
      contentState,
      'apply-entity'
    );

    let collapsed = selection.merge({
                        anchorOffset: selection.getEndOffset(), 
                        focusOffset: selection.getEndOffset()
                      });

    let newEditorState = EditorState.forceSelection(linked, collapsed);

    this.setState({
      showURLInput: false,
      editorState: newEditorState
    }, () => {
      setTimeout(() => {

        this.refs.editor.focus();

        const {editorState} = this.state;
        let selection = editorState.getSelection();

        let cs = Modifier.insertText(
          editorState.getCurrentContent(),
          selection,
          ' '
        );

        const newEditorState = EditorState.push(
          editorState,
          cs,
          'insert-text'
        );

        this.setState({editorState: newEditorState});
       }, 10);
    });
}
```